# How to Fix "Version 1.8.0_265 of the JVM is not suitable for this product." in Eclipse on MAC OS [Not Windows]

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-8

I installed jdk 1.8. Now when I launch eclipse I get the error "Version 1.8.0_265 of the JVM is not suitable for this product" Version 11 or greater is required. Any idea how to fix this? all the answers I found were for windows.

Comment: The version of eclipse you have installed require java 11 most probably. What version did you install? Try downgrading.

Comment: So an old Eclipse would fix it? Will try that. thanks!

Comment: The answer is the same for macOS, Linux or Windows. You must use at least Java 11 for the current Eclipse or go back to an older Eclipse release to run with Java 8. Java 11 and the current Java 15 are both available for macOS.

Comment: The error literally tells you what to do: install Java 11, not Java 8 (1.8).

Comment: yea but i need to use java 8 not anything later. Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot use anything other than Java 8 on your dev machine, then will have to use an older version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a newer JVM. On macOS you can easily install the newest JVM via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Or you can install [eclipse via homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/eclipse-java#default) and get the JDK installed as well automatically.